# Matlab indices in subplot

Tags: matlab, subplot, indices

I am trying to create a time array between -10 and 10 ms with 1000 samples . Then I want to create subplots corresponding to different amplitudes and frequencies for the sine function. However, since I am plotting for -10 to 10 milliseconds, I get the following error : Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

```
ms = linspace(-10,10,1000);
v1=7.5*sin(2*pi*100*ms);
subplot(3,1,1);
x = ms;
y1 = v1(x);
plot(x,y1)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `y1 = v1(x);`? If `x == ms` and you've already calculated `v1` why not just do `plot(ms, v1)`?

Answer (score 0):

As excaza mentioned, all you need to do is plot(ms,v1)

```
ms = linspace(-10,10,1000);
v1=7.5*sin(2*pi*100*ms);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(ms,v1);
```

and then do the same for your phase subplot.

The reason you're getting this error is that v1(x) is not a legal operation. v1 here is simply an array of numbers, so you cannot feed it x as an input. You can however find the values of the array by calling v(i), where i=1,2,...,length(v1), which will give you the i'th element of the v1 array.